# Deployment solution automatic compile

Tags: java, svn, deployment

At the moment I use SVN to manage java source code.  Is there a solution out there whereby I can check in code and have the new code automatically compiled into a JAR file?  Somehow the check in would need to trigger the compile process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) tool. [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) would be a good choice (I've been using it the past year and it works really well)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a CI server; the server can sit on another machine (the build server) and get the latest commit, build it, and compile it to a JAR. (Of course, this isn't really ideal, on large projects [due to lots of changes being submitted, and so on], but on personal things it should work to a reasonable degree).

Comment: CI is **especially** useful on large projects and any decent CI engine can deal with high number of commits. No, really, I don't get your point about large projects.

Comment: Pascal: Obviously, CI is useful, I was referring to the automatic building of every commit, (*that's* not useful, on large projects).

Comment: I don't agree with you. Having a build of every commit allows the devs to know exactly when the build breaks, and is not an extreme charge to the CI server.

Comment: @Valentin: Yes, but you don't want large projects building when they may take hours. It is typical to break your build process up, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of continuous integration programs which do this very thing.  Two I've used are [Bamboo (commercial)](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/) and CruiseControl (open source).  Bamboo is about 1000x easier to setup then CruiseControl, and really pays for itself after you've created a hundred build plans or so. With CruiseControl you will have killed yourself long before you get to your hundred build plan.